# How to delete photos ONLY from google photos backup?

Tags: backup, google-photos, google-backup

I backed up some photos in my android device to Google Photos.
I want to un-backup them. I want them to stay only internally on my device.
But if I delete photos from the app it deletes them also from my device.
Is there a way to delete individual photos from the backup and let them stay on my device?

I can of course download them from Google Photos, then delete them from Google Photos, and then transfer them to my device. But I need them to be in the same directories they were in in the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can uninstall the "Google Photos Backup" from your device or simply sign out from the account in the Photos app. Then go to the web-version of Google Photos (photos.google.com) and delete the photos.

- Go to photos.google.com and login using the Google account you're
  using on your device.
- Place your cursor over items you want to move to trash. At the top
  left corner of each item, click the select icon . (Or hold down SHIFT
  to select a range.)
- At the top right, click the trash icon.

I tried it personally (after signing out in the Google Photos app) and I'm sure it won't delete the photos from your phone.

Comment: It seems that it works even when "Back up & Sync" setting is off. I tried to delete a photo from web application and it still is on my phone. Strange is that I don't see backup button again on that photo.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Photos app is a bit tricky, because even disabling sync it still keeps deleting pictures. What I recommend you is to uninstall the app from your phone, and if it's not possible then disable it from Settings. Newest versions of android allow you to do that.

I personally use FolderSync to sync pictures from my device to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

[image: A]
[image: A]
[image: A]

Simply go to **Settings** - **Apps** - **Google Photos** - **Permissions** and uncheck the **Storage** button. That's it.